# During the 56th month or the 57th month?

Tags: logarithms

A car depreciates in value according to the model
$$V=Ak^t$$
where £$V$ is the value of the car $t$ months from when it was new.
Its value when new was £$12499$ and $36$ months later its value was £$7000$.

Find the value of $A$
\begin{align}
Ak^0 & = 12499 \\
\Rightarrow A & = 12499 \\ 
\end{align}
Find the value of $k$
\begin{align}
12499k^{36} & = 7000 \\
\Rightarrow k^{36} & = \frac{7000}{12499} \\ 
\Rightarrow k & = \left(\frac{7000}{12499}\right)^{\frac{1}{36}} \\ 
\Rightarrow k & = 0.984025... \\ 
\end{align}

The value of this car first dropped below £$5000$ $\color{red}{during}$ the $n$th month from new. Find the value of $n$.

\begin{align}
12499\cdot0.984025^n & = 5000 \\
\Rightarrow 0.984025^n & = \frac{5000}{12499} \\ 
\Rightarrow n\log 0.984025 & = \log \frac{5000}{12499} \\ 
\Rightarrow n & = \frac{\log \frac{5000}{12499}}{\log 0.984025} \\ 
\Rightarrow n & = 56.893449... \\ 
\end{align}
So therefore since $56<n<57$ it was $\color{red}{during}$ the $56$th month that the value of this car first dropped below £$5000$.

The problem is that the Mark Scheme is only accepting the answer $n=57$.

How can it be during the $57$th month if we're beginning at $0$ months?

Comment: At the *end* of the 56th month value is $>5000$, since the figure you obtained is $56.89..$, thus "during the 57th month" is the correct answer

Comment: You mean at the end of the $57$th month. See it is confusing it's not just me. ^^ I understand now though. It's like when we turn 18 we're actually living our 19th year.

Comment: Yep. $0-$end of $1$ = year 1, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is perfect.
You're getting the answer as 56.893449... , this means that the value of car drops down to £5000 **after 56th month** not in the 56th month.

This implies the answer is during 57th month.

To understand this an analogy may be used. *The year 2016 is in 21st century not 20th century.*